# R: How To Generate 15 Random Numbers random numbers from 1:10 With Strange Conditions

Tags: r

How To Generate 15 Random Numbers random numbers from 1:10, making sure A) Each number appear AT LEAST once and B) No number appears THREE times

I know how to use the normal sample function with replace = True and False. But this question is totally different, argh....

```
sample(1:10, 15, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: A "brute force" approach would be to use a while loop and keep generating samples of 15 until the two conditions are met. For such a small sample size that would not take long but would not scale well to huge sample sizes.

Comment: `sample(c(sample(10),sample(10,5)))` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with...

```
sample(c(1:10, sample(10, 5)))
```

The sequence `1:10` is combined with five random numbers from `1:10`.  The outer `sample` shuffles the whole lot.